# how to use jade/pug conditionals inside a script block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i'm struggling to get this working. im actually using Chart.js and trying to populate my graphs with arrays of data. 
so my code looks like

```
block lower-scripts
script.
    var data = {
        labels : [
            each visit in visitstats
                #{visit.date}, 
        ],
```

the output i get looks like

```
<script>var data = {
labels : [
    each visit in visitstats
        04/17/2016, 
],
```

and i dont think that is right. should it print the each statement out into the html output?

I've tried following a few questions but cant get this working.
It doesn't look like the each statement runs. tried using the - to make it run. tried the pipe in front of the js to make it the exception. nothing.
can anyone show me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: I usually do this by putting the array or object in a hidden input tag and then when required in frontend js, I get the value of this input tag and parse it.

Comment: clever. do you have an example you could sanitise and put up as an answer?

Comment: I have also thought it ought to be possible to ajax it into the page on document ready. but my ajax chops aren't up to that right now.

Comment: why use an extra ajax request that is not required. wait, i'll put my approach as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a hidden input tag in your body in jade e.g.

```
body
  input(type="hidden", id="visit-stats-json", value= JSON.stringify(visitstats) )

  script.
    var visitStatsValue = document.getElementById("visit-stats-json");
    var visitStatsJSON = JSON.parse( visitStatsValue );
    var labelsArray = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < visitStatsJSON.length; i++ )
    {
      var visit = visitStatsJSON[i];
      labelsArray.push( visit.date );
    }//for

    var data = { labels: labelsArray };
```

Now your data variable should have the value you want.

Edit:
I use exactly the same syntax and it works. Please note that there is a space after `value=`. If it still doesn't work, you can also try following way to achieve the same result:

```
-var visitStatsString = JSON.stringify(visitstats);
input(type="hidden", id="visit-stats-json", value= visitStatsString )
```

Comment: mike, thanks for the comprehensive reply. its just what i need. apart from the fact i can't get it to work. JSON.stringify( visitstats ) never spits anything out. do i need to do anything to make it run as js since its inside the html block? like preprend the - tag?

Comment: thanks for the update. i did indeed get the original line working, which was good. not sure why it wouldn't. 

i did also have to add .value to the sixth line so that the JSON.parse function could actually get at the contents of the object the htmlElement contained.

what i really liked about your answer was the scalability. i need only add two more lines and i can array the other contents of the results, which is brilliant.

great reply, thanks for taking the time out to help me.

Comment: thanks @bytejunkie :) . mark as answer if it worked for you please.

Comment: @bytejunkie no you've marked it. Just saw as I submitted the comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can use inline interpolation:

```
script.
  var visitstats = #[JSON.stringify(visitstats)];
  ...
```